# PLS-00201: identifier 'GETALLNAMES' must be declared

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am working on store procedure.I write a procedure in oracle 11g and calling the procedure in my java application.Here is my procedure

```
create or replace procedure getAllNames
is
CustomerName varchar2(30);
BEGIN
select name INTO CustomerName from customer;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CustomerName);
END;
/
```

When i call the procedure in java it is giving me the error

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'GETALLNAMES' must be declared
```

Tell me what is the mistake i am doing here. I'll be thankful.... :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the Java code you're using to call the SP.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You can call the procedure by one of 2 ways in java or any other external application.

1. Connecting to same schema where procedure resides.
2. Or give execute permission on the proc to the schema/user you are logged in in java

Previous Answer:

It is a good practice using scheme name before procedure name and call it in same manner.

```
create or replace procedure GETALLNAMES
as
CustomerName varchar2(30);
BEGIN
select name INTO CustomerName from customer;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CustomerName);
END;
/
```

Comment: Are you connecting to same schema while calling the procedure. Else you need to give execute permission on the proc to the schema/user you are logged in in java.